# Open the official Apple Transporter app with params

Tags: ios, terminal, applications, bash

I am looking for a way to automate the deploy of my React Native application built with Expo.

I am using the transporter app (not Xcode) to upload my app to the apple store.

```bsh
echo ''
echo '==============================='
echo ' Download archive.ipa'
echo '==============================='
echo ''
APP_IPA = $(curl -o app-ios.ipa "$(expo url:ipa)")
echo $APP_IPA

open .
open /Applications/Transporter.app
echo '=> You can upload the .ipa with Transporter'
```

When I execute my bash script I have this result:
[image]

#### Problem

I need to drag and drop my `app-ios.ipa` to the Transporter app.

[image]

#### Question: can I add an extra param when I open an app?

I want to pass a file as a param, maybe something like this

```bsh
open /Applications/Transporter.app --file="app-ios.ipa"
```

Comment: Did you check with whoever builds/distributes this application whether this is actually possible?

Comment: It's an official Apple application but I can't find documentation about it